# Integrar terminal POS GEOCOM o TRANSACT con mi software de facturación

Tags: api, librería

estoy queriendo integrar el POS ya sea de GEOCOM o TRANSACT para enviar el monto a pagar desde mi software de facturación al POS y una ves allí el cliente pueda pagar con tarjeta.

Así mismo también quiero que una vez el pago haya sido realizado con éxito envíe información a mi software para que este recién allí imprima el ticket.

Alguien sabe como se hace esto o cuales son los pasos? Me parece que debe ser una librería la que debo usar pero no se si es de uso publico o debería hablar con las empresas GEOCOM y TRANSACT para que me la provean.

Muchas gracias

Comment: pudiste con esto?

Comment: No, me comuniqué con geocom directo pero nunca respondieron. Imagino se necesita un controlador o driver que ellos deberian proveer